# Can't select the first row in a slickgrid after changing its data

Tags: slickgrid

I have a single slickgrid that uses a dataview with the row selection model.  I frequently assign a completely different array to the dataview, switching the data in this grid.

I use this function to swap datasets in the grid:

```
function setData(dataArray, uniqueIdFieldName) {
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(dataArray, uniqueIdFieldName)
    dataView.endUpdate();
    grid.resizeCanvas();
    grid.invalidate();  
}
```

The first time I use this function (to load the initial data into an empty grid), everything works great. Every time after that, it loads the data fine but has a selection bug.  I can't select the first row in the grid.  However, if I select a row other than the first, the bug seems to correct itself and I can then select the first row again.  When I change the data again with my function, I once again can't select the first row.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and solution.  The problem is slickgrid is keeping all the data about the active cell/row even after you completely change it's data with setItems().  The internal variable activeCell is still set to an index value, even though no cells are selected anymore.  The solution is to call grid.resetActiveCell() before changing the data.  So the working code looks like this:

```
function setData(dataArray, uniqueIdFieldName) {
    grid.resetActiveCell(); //THIS LINE ADDED
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(dataArray, uniqueIdFieldName)
    dataView.endUpdate();
    grid.resizeCanvas();
    grid.invalidate();  
}
```

It seems to me that this is a bug in slickGrid.  The setItems() function should reset the selection variables internally before changing the rows, since obviously the current selection is going to be null and void after resetting the items and not doing so leaves the entire selection model in a faulty state.